# Running a delayed loop of functions in javascript console

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, console, delayed-execution

hope you're doing well-
I'm having some issues with getting a delayed loop going in JavaScript console. For context, I've been tasked with building a list of emails from our CRM, but the platform does not allow export of this data beyond listing it all in a search.

I've created a blank array to push emails to, we'll worry about getting this data out after.:

```
emailsList = [];
```

So I need to the following for each row of the table:

```
function clickPopup() {
//Click User Code to Trigger Ajax Popup
document.querySelector("#tblReport > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > td:nth-child(2) > a").click();

}

function getEmailTextAndClose() {
// Grab Dom Content in email variable
var email = document.querySelector("#email_compose_link").innerText;
// Push email to emailList array
emailsList.push(email);
parent.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()
}
```

these all work fine, but where I'm struggling is in putting these into a loop with a delay, the popup needs a second to pull the content via ajax. So what I've tried:

```
emailsList = [];

function clickPopup() {
//Click User Code to Trigger Ajax Popup
document.querySelector("#tblReport > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > td:nth-child(2) > a").click();

}

function getEmailTextAndClose() {
// Grab Dom Content in email variable
var email = document.querySelector("#email_compose_link").innerText;
// Push email to emailList array
emailsList.push(email);
parent.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()
}

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
setTimeout(function() {
  // after 1000ms, call the `setTimeout` callback
  // In the meantime, continue executing code below
  setTimeout(function() {
    getEmailTextAndClose() //runs second after 11000ms
  },1000)

  clickPopup() //runs first, after 10ms
},10)
}
```

And:

```
emailsList = [];

function getEmailTextAndClose() {
// Grab Dom Content in email variable
var email = document.querySelector("#email_compose_link").innerText;
// Push email to emailList array
emailsList.push(email);
parent.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()
}

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   clickPopup(i);
}

function clickPopup(i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector("#tblReport > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > td:nth-child(2) > a").click();
    setTimeout(getEmailTextAndClose() 2000)
  }, 2000);
  getEmailTextAndClose();
}
```

All these configurations either dont delay the second function, or dont increment the i's in our query selector. Am I going about this all wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a promise with the code that triggers the ajax function:

```
function clickPopup() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
//Click User Code to Trigger Ajax Popup
document
  .querySelector(
    "#tblReport > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > td:nth-child(2) > a"
  )
  .click();
  resolve();
 });
}

function getEmailTextAndClose() {
 // Grab Dom Content in email variable
 var email = document.querySelector("#email_compose_link").innerText;
 // Push email to emailList array
 emailsList.push(email);
 parent.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
}

clickPopup().then(function () {
  getEmailTextAndClose();
});
```